# How make an app without menu? Android

Tags: android, menu, android-actionbar

I use this for change the menu:

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_log_in, menu);
    return true;
}
```

but...

If i want that my activity haven't menu, how make it?

I want make activities without menu because i don't have navigation in this scenes. How make it?

Comment: Just remove the the snippet from your code, Extend the activity to Activity (android.app.activity).

Comment: Thx. Fixed the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove these two methods in your Activity:

```
    @Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_del, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Comment: If you are ok with the answer then you can up vote it.